# DocuSign integration using rest api with SPA

Tags: docusignapi

I am using Application Code Grant for angular for angular application.

Issue1- Refresh token is not valid for next 2days, even with signature extended, how can I extend access token for next 30days?

Issue2- Viewing that document

```
error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token % in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse message:
```

"Http failure during parsing for demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/…"
name: "HttpErrorResponse" ok: false status: 200 statusText: "OK" url: "demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/CCCC-XXXXX-a54115-ddff-588/envelopes/XXXXXX-ccccc-30c1ce29f66a/documents/1

```
header = header.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT');
    header = header.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    header = header.append('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    header = header.append('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
    header = header.append('accept', 'application/pdf');
    headers = headers.append('Authorization', "Bearer " + token);
```

Step 1- `https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature extended&client_id=39b5f6fb-97ca-XXXXXXXXXXXXX&state=a39fh23hnf23XXXXX&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4200/callbackdocusign`
Result - Success

Step 2 - Fetch access token using Code

```
//curl--header "Authorization: Basic BASE64_COMBINATION_OF_INTEGRATION_AND_SECRET_KEYS"
    //--data "grant_type=authorization_code&code=YOUR_AUTHORIZATION_CODE"
    //--request POST https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token
   let key = btoa(environment.client_id_authentication_code_grant + ":" + environment.secret_key_authentication_code_grant);
    let paramInHeader: any = [];
    paramInHeader.push({ Name: 'Content-Type', Value: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' });
    paramInHeader.push({ Name: 'Authorization', Value: "Basic " + key });
    paramInHeader.push({ Name: 'Accept', Value: "application/json" });
    var details = {
        'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
        'code': code
    };
```

Post https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token
Result - Success

Step 3- Fetching user info

```
https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/userinfo
headers = headers.append('Authorization', "Bearer " + token);
headers = headers.append('content-type', 'application/json');
headers = headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

Result - Success

Step 4- Fetching refresh token

```
//curl--header "Authorization: Basic MjMwNTQ2.....Y4MmM3YmYyNzZlOQ=="
    //--data "grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=ey4fd.....3d31d`
    //--request POST https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token


let key = btoa(environment.client_id_authentication_code_grant + ":" + environment.secret_key_authentication_code_grant);
    let paramInHeader: any = [];
    paramInHeader.push({ Name: 'Content-Type', Value: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' });
    paramInHeader.push({ Name: 'Authorization', Value: "Basic " + key });
    paramInHeader.push({ Name: 'Accept', Value: "application/json" });

    var details = {'grant_type': 'refresh_token','refresh_token': refresh_token};
```

Result - Success

Answer (score 0):

### Issue 1- Refresh token is not valid for next 2 days, even with signature extended, how can I extend access token for next 30 days?

Authorization Code grant is not supported from a browser-based app since there is no way for the app to protect the client ID secret. This restriction is from the OAuth RFC.

From a browser-based app, only Implicit grant (8 hour access tokens) is supported. If you have a backend to the app, and the app user logs into the backend, then the backend could implement Authorize Code grant and use the refresh token for renewals.

### Issue 2- Viewing that document

The [EnvelopeDocuments.get](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopedocuments/get/) returns the actual PDF document, which is a binary file. So it is not JSON and you should not try to parse it as JSON. Just display it to the user or let them download it.

Comment: Issue 1 - Now I am using Code Grant and fetched token with refresh token, still it is not working, next day when I am using same token generated with refresh_token is giving error

Issue 2- How can I get uri or path of that file - so that user can click that link - view status - download ?